# joomla - avoid model duplication between admin vs component packages

Tags: joomla

I'm developing a custom joomla component and have CRUD requirements on my database tables. In most of the examples i've seen, the default and admin pacakges both have their own model folders, and their seems to be a large amount of duplication. Is there a simple stragety to define the models and tables once within the admin section and then allow the default component to reuse the logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can reuse admin models by adding this into your front end component's main file:

```
$controller->addModelPath(JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'models');
```

You can reuse tables by adding this into your front end component's main file:

```
JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'tables');
```